# Angular 2 Front End + oAuth2 + Go REST

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, angular

I am struggling to understand how to integrate oAuth2 with Angular 2 as Front end and REST API in Go.

Basically i want user to login using their Facebook, LinkedIn, google+. I want my WEB API in GO to secure requests using some kind of token authentication.

Can anyone please point me in right direction how to do using all these 3 (Angular 2, 0Auth2 and Go as REST

Thanks

Comment: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2